# Ошибка "Use of unassigned local variable"

Tags: c#

Как исправить?
По идее все верно, не пойму что не так.

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: компилятор сомневается, что переменной res наверняка будет присвоено значение. Вам придется инициализировать переменную - присвоить ей любое значение, например 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо в любом случае инициализировать переменную перед первым использованием на чтение.
Например:

```
double res = 0;
```

Проблема в том, что в вашем коде цикл может и не выполниться ни разу. Если длина массивов будет нулевой, тогда переменная не будет проинициализирована.